# Excel - Substract number from previous cell and put results into a extra row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table in excel in a form like:

[image]

Now I would like to have a formula which puts results of substraction in row "C" which would look like:

[image]

The results are calculated on basis:

- A3-A2
- A5-A4
- A7-A6
- A9-A8

How to create a formula to have the results of substitution on the same line where the "minuend" is placed but on column "C"
Or the formula could be created in that way to place the results on lines where the value of the Row "B" is "0".

Comment: is it always one to one, as in groups of two?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is always one to one, an in and an out then:

```
=IF(B2=0,A2-A1,"")
```

[image]